# Swift UIDatePicker doesn't show initial value

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a `UITextField` that uses a `UIDatePicker` as its input method as so:

```
lazy var starttime_text_field: UITextField = {
    let text_field = UITextField()
    ...

    let date_picker = UIDatePicker()
    date_picker.minimumDate = Date()
    date_picker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())

    date_picker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    date_picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleStarttimePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    text_field.inputView = date_picker

    ...
    return text_field
}()
```

When I select the text field, I would like for the first date that shows up in the picker to appear as the text field's text. However, that doesn't happen; only when I scroll through the picker does the picker's value appear in the text field. I've tried changing `.valueChanged` to other things, but I still haven't gotten it to work. How can I achieve this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use textfield delegate methods to set values when editing begins and ends.

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

The event for picker is triggered only if the value is changed. So the default/selected value must be updated when textfield is setup or when editing mode changes.